# Passing value of EditText to service

Tags: android

I have a simple Activity which creates a foreground service. I would like to pass value from EditText to Service as the amount to which the screen should be dimmed. The MainActivity looks like this:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.net.wifi.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.provider.*;
import android.text.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText edDim = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DimVal);
        edDim.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

        Button btnStart =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
                intent.putExtra("DimVal",edDim.getText());
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        Button btnStop =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
                }
            });

    }
}
```

This is the service:

```
    package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.provider.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MyService extends Service
{
public int timeVal;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        Toast.makeText(this,"Usługa uruchomiona",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        timeVal = intent.getIntExtra("DimVal",100);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mComnReceiver,
                              new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        Notification note = new Notification(0, null,
        System.currentTimeMillis());note.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        this.startForeground(1,note);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Usługa zatrzymana",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/

    private BroadcastReceiver mComnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context p1, Intent p2)
        {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
              getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            boolean isWiFi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();


            //NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo)
                //p2.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(isWiFi){
                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, timeVal);

            }else{

                Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 300);

            }

        }


    };
}
```

But the above code does not work. Also how can I make the service check if the WiFi is on every 5 minutes?  I realize that this code may not be the best solution of the problem but this is the first Android program I've written (thus the commented code). 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Can you post your LogCat error please?

Comment: have you debug your code

Comment: Why don't you create a static String object and then put value of `EditText` in it and then call that static string into your Service Class?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi using static is not consider good practice

Comment: Does not work means that the value isn't read by the service and the default is put in.
@ALFANSO I wrote this in AIDE for Android not in AndroidStudio so the answer is no.

Comment: try intent.geExtra("key");

Comment: you are getting value or not

Comment: Will try getExtra, withthe code I used the value is set to 100 (he default put in getIntExtra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see issue is in this line of code

```
intent.putExtra("DimVal",edDim.getText());
```

Here you should do as

```
intent.putExtra("DimVal",Integer.valueOf(edDim.getText().toString));
```

EditText [getText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) i.e. `edDim.getText()` will give you Editable not the value inside. Also as you will do `edDim.getText().toString` will give you String value which you require to change to Integer before passing.

Note: You require to put null and check validation for edDim before passing value in intent; else it may give you runtimeerror.

Regarding the checking of WiFi it would be nice to create a broadcast receiver which receives updates for connection check and in that if connectivity is there then you can check whether it is Wifi or Mobile data and return false if mobile data. This way you do not require to check every five minutes which may lead to battery drainage.

You can check this android developer post for [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Comment: thank you that solved it. As for the Broacast receiver it is declared in Myservice.java if I got what you've written right.

Answer (score 1):

```
        public void timerForWifiCheck(long intervalVal, long countVal) {

                    new SCBP_TimerClass(intervalVal, countVal) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long tickTime) {

                            //Wifi checking code write here
                      if(SCBP_NetworkUtil.checkInternetConnection(Context)){
                      //Do what you wnat e.g
                      finish()
                    }else{
                       //Return with some error code or msg
                    }

                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            //code when the  timer finshes 
                        }
                    }.start();
                }






    For this You need to add the below  two classes:


        public abstract class TimerClass {

        /**
         * Millis since epoch when alarm should stop.
         */
        private final long mMillisInFuture;

        /**
         * The interval in millis that the user receives callbacks
         */
        private final long mCountdownInterval;

        private long mStopTimeInFuture;

        private long mPauseTime;

        private boolean mCancelled = false;

        private boolean mPaused = false;

        /**
         * @param millisInFuture
         *            The number of millis in the future from the call to
         *            {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and
         *            {@link #onFinish()} is called.
         * @param countDownInterval
         *            The interval along the way to receive {@link #onTick(long)}
         *            callbacks.
         */
        public SCBP_TimerClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            mMillisInFuture = millisInFuture;
            mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
        }

        /**
         * Cancel the countdown.
         * 
         * Do not call it from inside CountDownTimer threads
         */
        public final void cancel() {
            mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
            mCancelled = true;
        }

        /**
         * Start the countdown.
         */
        public synchronized final SCBP_TimerClass start() {
            if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
                onFinish();
                return this;
            }
            mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
            mCancelled = false;
            mPaused = false;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Pause the countdown.
         */
        public long pause() {
            mPauseTime = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            mPaused = true;
            return mPauseTime;
        }

        /**
         * Resume the countdown.
         */
        public long resume() {
            mStopTimeInFuture = mPauseTime + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            mPaused = false;
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
            return mPauseTime;
        }

        /**
         * Callback fired on regular interval.
         * 
         * @param millisUntilFinished
         *            The amount of time until finished.
         */
        public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

        /**
         * Callback fired when the time is up.
         */
        public abstract void onFinish();

        private static final int MSG = 1;

        // handles counting down
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                synchronized (SCBP_TimerClass.this) {
                    if (!mPaused) {
                        final long millisLeft = mStopTimeInFuture
                                - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                        if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                            onFinish();
                        } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                            // no tick, just delay until done
                            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
                        } else {
                            long lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                            onTick(millisLeft);

                            // take into account user's onTick taking time to
                            // execute
                            long delay = lastTickStart + mCountdownInterval
                                    - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                            // special case: user's onTick took more than
                            // interval to
                            // complete, skip to next interval
                            while (delay < 0)
                                delay += mCountdownInterval;

                            if (!mCancelled) {
                                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        }

public class NetworkUtil {
    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


    Hope this will help you to some extent.Cheers!
```

Comment: Will try taht one also. Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to know whether network connection is there of not , drop me a line will also help you in that

Comment: BroPl just check above and see if it can meet your requirements.. i have edited the preious solution with network check code inside the timerForWifiCheck method, and have added one more class